# How to hide a sub-mesh from SFB file in ArCore Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm rendering a SFB file which I generated from an FBX file using ArCore's sceneform in Android.
Now, I want to hide a part of this 3D model at runtime programmatically. How can I achieve this in Android?

Answer (score 2):

So far, I didn't find any way till ArCore v1.9 to hide a part of SFB file. 
So, I'm using two model files (fbx/obj) and then at first, I rendered generated two SFB files in a separate Nodes and then added these two Node objects into a single Node. This is working seamless.

Comment: Can you please tell in a bit more detail how you did this? Specially the part where you rendered two SFB files in separate nodes and then making one node from it?

Comment: @PHPDeveloper We can add multiple nodes to one another. I simply created two separate nodes in ArCore and rendered different renderable (.sfb) on these nodes. Then, I created a third node added these two nodes into this. And, added this third node to AR scene.